# How to allow users to add 0 after decimal in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, regex

How to allow users to add 0 after decimal in AngularJS ?

i have added ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(.[0-9]{0,2})?$/" step="1" but it is not allowing 1.0X or 1.X0. But it allows 1.1x.

Comment: Could you clarify? Also, please add all the relevant HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean the `X` stands for a digit.

The dot `.` in your regex is a metacharacter for match any character
but newline. If you want to match a dot as a literal you have to escape it.

`^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$`